# Puppeteer Can't Detect Selector

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape this website: https://www.vivino.com/CA/en/caymus-vineyards-special-selection-cabernet-sauvignon/w/66294?year=2017&price_id=27210070

```
    ...
    let wine = wineLinks[i];
    console.log(wine);
    let winePage = await browser.newPage();
    await winePage.goto(wine.link, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});

    const alcohol = await winePage.evaluate(() => document.querySelector("div.wrap div#wine-page-lower-section div.vintagePage__bottom--1fcqg div.inner div:nth-child(5) table tbody tr:nth-child(5) td span").textContent);
    console.log(alcohol);
```

However, it says the following error:

Error [TypeError]: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'textContent')

When testing the above selector in the browser, it returns what I need. Any suggestions what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Page loading usually takes time so you'd want to wait a few more seconds before running `evaluate()`. Best way is to wait for the selector and then running it.

Comment: I tried adding a timeout and I'm scraping some other values which seem to work fine. However, this particular one is causing issues

Comment: Did you try to use `waitForSelector`?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work putting multiple scrolls to load all the content of the page as parts of it get loaded after you scroll down past a couple points. However it is unnecessary, as all information is loaded with `window.__PRELOADED_STATE__` you can just evaluate that and get any information you like, take a look at the code below.

Code :

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let browser;
(async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: "new"});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    
    let url = "https://www.vivino.com/CA/en/caymus-vineyards-special-selection-cabernet-sauvignon/w/66294?year=2017&price_id=27210070";

    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "domcontentloaded", timeout: 30000 });
    await page.waitForSelector("body");

    const preloadedState = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return window.__PRELOADED_STATE__;
    });

    console.log(preloadedState.vintagePageInformation.vintage.wine_facts.alcohol); // the alchol content

    //console.log(preloadedState.vintagePageInformation); // all info on the page

})().catch(err => console.error(err)).finally(() => browser ?. close());
```

**Update** : You need to put a check if the `alcohol` field exists or not, as on some pages it doesn't exist. [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmor1.jpg) of the code below.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let browser;
(async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    
    let url = "https://www.vivino.com/explore?e=eJwlykEOQDAQRuHb_Eupsp1LiI2IyKhqmigyGvT2Gjbv27wgVBcawW-kEPihUikFk6htYHI6HFTCLXSxeBt5xS4zzfY02KdEwtFv7hz5ssLO4o79kP8P_VP91C8jayMw";

    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "networkidle0", timeout: 30000 });
    await page.waitForSelector("body");

    //this won't get all the links on the page, you to get need to scroll down first
    let links = await page.$$eval('a[data-testid=vintagePageLink]', el => el.map(x => x.getAttribute('href')));

    let wines = [];
    for(let link of links) {
        await page.goto(`https://www.vivino.com${link}`, {waitUntil: "networkidle0", timeout: 30000 });
        await page.waitForSelector("body");

        const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
            return window.__PRELOADED_STATE__.vintagePageInformation.vintage;
        });

        let alcohol = (data.wine_facts.alcohol) ? data.wine_facts.alcohol : null;

        wines.push({ name: data.name, alcohol: alcohol});
    }

    console.log(wines);

})().catch(err => console.error(err)).finally(() => browser ?. close());
```

Comment: I tried to do this, however I'm looping through links and it worked for the first link, but at the second link the value is undefined.

Comment: @AG you need to put a simple check if the `alcohol` field exists or not on the other pages, I've added an update to the answer above as an example.